# Can't auto submit when press enter key

Tags: jquery, html, validation, form-submit

I have HTML code below. Auto submit when press enter key doesn't work. I try to add jQuery, the required input doesn't work. What should I do?

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <form action='<?php echo site_url(); ?>account_c/login' method="POST">
        <div class="text-left form-group">
            <span>Email</span><br>
            <input type="email" id="EM" name="EM" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="text-left form-group">
            <span>Password</span><br>
            <input type="password" id="PS" name="PS" class="form-control" minlength="8" placeholder="Your Password" required><!--<i class="fa fa-eye" onmouseover="mouseoverPass();" onmouseout="mouseoutPass();"></i>-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <span class="text-center"><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/home/forgotpasswordmail">Forgot Password?</a></span>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" class="btn btn-info" style=" color:black;" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like your tags are unbalanced (check the `<form>` opening and closing tags, as well as the first `<div>`, there's also some possible issue with your `<a>` tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code is not proper.

The issue is with `<` and `>`characters.

e.g. here,

`<form action='<?php echo site_url(); ?>account_c/login' method="POST">`

You have to escape them for the form to generate the URLs properly.

Check if the action url is created properly on page, I bet it won't be.
Your form is actually getting submitted but not going anywhere.

Try with,

```
<form action='&#60?php echo site_url(); ?&#62account_c/login' method="POST">
```

Similarly,

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/home/forgotpasswordmail""
```

should be,

```
<a href="&#60?php echo site_url(); ?&#62/home/forgotpasswordmail">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#your-id").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#your-id").click();
    }
});
```

try this

Comment: Why wouldn't an <input type="submit"> submit a form automatically on enter button?